# (discord.py) How can I detect custom and default emojis

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make an `enlarge` command which turns an emoji into a png/gif form like this

[image]

Here's my code so far

```
@client.command()
async def enlarge(ctx, emoji: discord.PartialEmoji = None):
    if not emoji:
        await ctx.send("You need to provide an emoji!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(emoji.url)
```

This works...but only with custom emojis. The command does not detect default emojis such as  or . I've tried everything I could but I just couldn't get it to detect default emojis. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [emoji library](https://emojis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for default emojis. Here is an example:

```
import emoji

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if emoji.emoji_count(message.content) > 0:
        await message.channel.send('You used a default emoji')
```

You can take a look the documentation.