# How do I check if a sent emote is a Discord default one and forbid the rest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to check if a sent emoji is a Discord emoji or not. If it is not, I want the following output:

```py
await ctx.channel.send(f"You can only use default discord emojis")
```

**This is my code so far:**

```py
@client.command()
async def reactrole(ctx, emoji=None, role: discord.Role=None,*,message=None):
  if emoji is None:
    await ctx.channel.send(f"say an emoji to use")
    return
  if role is None:
    await ctx.channel.send(f"select a role to use then backward")
    return
  if ctx.guild.me.top_role.position < role.position:
    await ctx.channel.send(f"role is above mine so i cant create the role reaction dickhead")
    return
```

Comment: Is this helping you? [How can I detect custom and default emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852882/discord-py-how-can-i-detect-custom-and-default-emojis)